# Regex. Get first half of a string. Possible?

Tags: regex, string

I want to get "12" if the string is "1212" and I want to get "5678" if the string is "56785678" in Regex, without using JS or any other language. Plain Regex. Possible?

OH! Yes, the original string will always be of even length (not strings like 123), and the first half will always be the same as the last half. I just want the half, and ultimately I don't care if it's the first one or the last one (since they are the same).

Comment: Regular expressions are nice for some things, but for others they are just a hassle. Why do you want to use regular expressions here, instead of just plain dividing the string in half (which is very easy)? What is the *actual* problem here? What are you really trying to do? And what do you mean by (paraphrased) "without using any language"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the two halves are the same you can use a backreference

```
^(.*)\1$
```

And your programming environment can then use the first capture group of the match.
If there is no such possibility (to get the capture group only), then use look ahead:

[`^(.*)(?=\1$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Oz0ZoU/1)

Be aware that a regular expression is not the optimal tool for this "problem": it has a *O(n²)* worst case time complexity. A plain string comparison of two halves, through code, will be more efficient.

Comment: That did it! You are amazing! Thank you so much!!!!! (I know I should not use five exclamation signs here, but the heck with it)

Comment: I just changed it to ^(\d*)(?=\1$) because I only get digits, but still, I would have never been able to get this in such a clean, elegant regex! Thank you again!